# How to move from one tableview to another tableview in viewController?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I have two view controllers(view1, view2) in that I added two table views(table1, table2),in that I want to move from 1st view controller's tableview to another view controller's table view, at didSelectRowAtIndexPath. In view1 I have an array called getArray I want to display this array in view2 (tableview2)
here is my code
In view2 I created two arrays

```
   NSMutableArray *getContestArray;
   NSMutableArray * getContestIdArray;
   UITableView *tableContest;

  if (indexPath.row==0)
    {
        NSLog(@"Going to exam Id Class");
        UIStoryboard *contestDetail =self.storyboard;
        view2 *contestVC =[contestDetail instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"view2VC"];
        [self presentViewController:contestVC animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
  else if (indexPath.row==1)
    {

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do something as below, This is just to give you basic idea to transfer data from one ViewController to another. Modify below code as per your requirement. Thanks!

**FirstViewController.h**

```
@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>
{
    NSArray *getArray;
}
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tbl1;
```

**FirstViewController.m**

```
#import "SecondViewController.h"

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return [getArray count];
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    SecondViewController *objController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SecondViewController"]; //Give SecondViewController as identifier name to your SecondViewController from Storyboard

    objController.array = [getArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:objController animated:YES];
}
```

**SecondViewController.h**

```
@interface SecondViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>
{

}
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tbl2;
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSArray *array;
```

**SecondViewController.m**

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return [array count];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make the array in your view2 as property like this:-

```
@property NSMutableArray *arr2;
```

and in did select of view1 write this code->

```
  SecondViewController *second=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"second"];
    second.arr2=getArray;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:second animated:YES];
```